# Forgetting to Close a ServerSocket

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp

If my program does not execute a `ServerSocket.close()` and/or `Socket.close()` before it terminates, the next time I start the program, it will always throw an `IOException` when attempting to start listening on a port.

This usually happens not because I forget to put a `close()` at the end of the program, rather when I force close the program and would never have a chance to execute `close()`. It seems like I have to log-out and log-in on my Linux machine for it to get rid of the "occupied socket". I was wondering if anyone know a way I could clear up any unclosed sockets in case the server is forcefully ended from Terminal or any other method?

I already tried disabling and enabling my network connections, still no luck.

Comment: How do you kill the process?By kill -9?

Comment: sorry, I am now unclear on the exact problem. In the question, you mentioned that you are "force closing the program", but in the comment to my answer you mentioned that you are worried about the program crashing by itself. Which scenario are you worried about? Is it both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to your believe, you are not terminating your program. If it yould have been, the socket would have been freed, and I don't believe you have found a bug in the linux kernel here :).

It might be possible that your main thread has terminated, but your application still has non-daemon threads running that will keep your JVM alive.

After creating your threads you have to call myThread.setDaemon(true).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `[setReuseAddress()][1]` on the ServerSocket before binding it? If not, then try that.

Comment: What do you mean by that? My program starts a ServerSocket like so...ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234); and waits for connection Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(). What am I suppose to add?

Comment: @AeroDroid Create an unbound server socket with `new ServerSocket()`, then call `setReuseAddress(true)` on it, and then bind it to an address by calling one of the `bind()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "netstat -a" command to check the status of that port.   I suspect it will be in CLOSE-WAIT.  This is a case of TCP working as designed and will show up in any language and OS.  Eventually the kernel will timeout waiting for your program to close the socket and clear it out.  You can reduce this timeout, but the best solution is to make sure your programs shuts down cleanly.

Comment: @JTON:But once a process is killed, aren't sockets fd's released immediatelly?You are right though about the comment of not being possible to reuse the sockets immediately.But why would they be in close-wait?

Comment: I think you're right. I bet it would be TIME-WAIT and not CLOSE-WAIT.  It's been a while since I've across this issue.

Comment: @JTON:If the process has spawned threads and is not forced kill, may be the process is still running in background and the fd's are still held?

Comment: That's why I was thinking TIME-WAIT instead.  That happens in TCP after the file descriptor is closed.  It's basically to provide any packets still on the network time to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since your concern is what will happen in case of an unexpected stop of JVM, what you need in my opinion, are shutdown hooks. Take a look at the following link:
http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20459/1954

Comment: Nope. it is not; Shutdown hooks WILL NOT help you at all. 1st, they are executed only if the process terminates normally (kill -TERM/9) won't execute the hooks. If the process terminates normally, the socket FDs will be properly free.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you bestsss, I realized that Shutdown Hooks will only run when I safely terminate. I actually think that I resolved this problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

What's your "program"? Does it own the process or it is just a some module to plug into a container. Terminating a process closes any sockets associated with the said process, so no need to explicit close() is needed, or not at least to prevent java.net.BindException.

Are you sure the program actually terminates its execution, that should your prime concern.

Answer (score -2):

sudo /sbin/service network restart

Answer (score -2):

`/etc/init.d/networking restart`